# Collapsible container/column. Adding more than one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down effect similar to this image: [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mju1t.gif), however with what I have so far: [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sfcm95yz/1/) I can't seem to figure out a way to add more than one link, if I do add just another content div it doesn't show up.. Hope someone can help, been losing sleep over this haha. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Projects</div>
  <div class="content" onclick="initContent('example')"><em>Example Project</em></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".header").click(function() {
  $header = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $(this).next();
  //checking if its already visible
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function() {});
  });
});
```

What I would try:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Projects</div>
  <div class="content" onclick="initContent('example')"><em>Example Project</em></div>
<div class="content" onclick="initContent('exampleNew')"><em>Example Project 2</em></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sfcm95yz/6/ see my code below yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify your JS and keep the existing markup, `.nextAll()` will select all of `$header`'s siblings (`.next()` only selects one sibling). You can also add a selector argument to be sure you only select elements with the class "content".

```
$(".header").click(function() {
    $header = $(this);
    //getting the sibling ".content" elements
    $content = $(this).nextAll(".content");
    //checking if its already visible
    $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function() {});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put all your links in a single content div:

https://jsfiddle.net/sfcm95yz/3/

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="item" onlclick="initContent('example')">
    <em>Example Project</em>
  </div>
  <div class="item" onlclick="initContent('example2')">
    <em>Example Project 2</em>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are sliding down the content div that is *right after* the header class element (`$content = $(this).next();`), which applies a `display: block` to it. If you add another content div, it isn't going to be **right after** that header and so won't be shown.

You can either change your JavaScript to target all content divs, or rearrange your HTML, something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Projects</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div onclick="initContent('example')">
      <em>Example Project</em>
    </div>
    <div onclick="initContent('example')">
      <em>Example Project 2</em>
    </div>
    <div onclick="initContent('example')">
      <em>Example Project 3</em>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```